# Localization in Flutter MaterialApp Widget parameters

Tags: localization, flutter

Following the tutorials at [1](https://flutter.io/tutorials/internationalization/) and [2](https://medium.com/@anilcan/flutter-internationalization-by-using-json-files-f91468d86df0) I am trying to set up localization for my flutter app. That works fine and I can use `I18n.of(context).trans(<key>)` to access translated strings in my widgets.

However I don't know how to access the translations in the `MaterialApp` top widget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/i18n/i18n.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/views/menu.dart';
import 'package:flutter\_localizations/flutter\_localizations.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      supportedLocales: [
        const Locale('en', 'US'),
        const Locale('de', 'DE'),
      ],
      localizationsDelegates: [
        const I18nDelegate(),
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate
      ],

      title: I18n.of(context).trans('title'), //FIXME doesn't work
      home: new Menu(),

    );
  }
}
```

For above code I get an exception because `I18n.of(context)` returns `null`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should use `onGenerateTitle` instead of `title` field :

```
MaterialApp(
   ...
   onGenerateTitle: (context) => I18n.of(context).trans('title'),
)
```